# Elastic search how to index a nested list

Tags: json, elasticsearch

How to  create index for nested data structure with list? There will be list of otherUserID's and I don't know how to index them with elasticsearch 6.5.

`UserID -> OtherUserID-> name:"text" , count : "long"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uses [nested data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/nested.html#nested) for creating such a field and indexing list of object.
Refer to the example below and modify it to your needs:

**Mapping:**

```
PUT testindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "nestedField": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "field1": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keywords": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "field2": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Adding documents:**

For single item in list:

```
PUT testindex/_doc/1
{
  "nestedField": [
    {
      "field1": "Some text",
      "field2": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

For multiple items in list:

```
PUT testindex/_doc/2
{
  "nestedField": [
    {
      "field1": "Some other text",
      "field2": 11
    },
    {
      "field1": "random value",
      "field2": 15
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you also add how to retrieve value by descending order of field2

Comment: Reffer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#nested-sorting) for sorting using nested field